# Horizontal Nested List using CSS

Tags: css, list, nested, horizontallist

I'm trying to create a horizontal list from a nested list markup, as an example I have the current markup:

```
<ul>
<li class="alone">List Item 1</li>
<li class="alone">List Item 2</li>
<li class="alone">List Item 3</li>
<li class="group">List Item 4
  <ul>
    <li class="not_alone">List Item 4a</li>
    <li class="not_alone">List Item 4b</li>
    <li class="not_alone">List Item 4c</li>
    <li class="not_alone">List Item 4d</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="alone">List Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to achieve something similar to this:

```
<style>
div { display: inline-block; }
.alone { background: #E5ECF9; border: 1px solid #336699; color: #336699;  }
.group { background: #FBE3E4; border: 1px solid #CC0000; color: #CC0000; }
.group .not_alone { background: #FBE3E4; border: 1px solid #CC0000; color: #CC0000; }
.item { padding: 2px; margin: 0 2px; }
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="alone item">List Item 1</div>
  <div class="alone item">List Item 2</div>
  <div class="alone item">List Item 3</div>
  <div class="group item">
    List Item 4
    <div class="group item">List Item 4a</div>
    <div class="group item">List Item 4b</div>
    <div class="group item">List Item 4c</div>
    <div class="group item">List Item 4d</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="alone item">List Item 5</div>
</div>
```

You can see a demo here http://jsbin.com/exivi5.

Is this possible using the existing nested list markup? Also, can I also keep the width of the ul parent list to 100% so it fits the entire viewport?

This needs to be compatible in FF, Webkit and IE7+ but will settle for IE8+ support.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question exactly? Don't you already have what you need in the div based markup, ready to be applied on the list elements?

Comment: using the ul-li elements instead of divs and the same classes, you don't get the same result??

Comment: No you don't get the exact same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding these css rules:

```
ul {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; float:left; display: inline;}
ul li {float:left; display: inline; margin: 0 5px; padding: 3px 2px;}
ul li ul {float:right;}
h2 {clear: left;}
```

with a bit of fiddling with margins & paddings it should look the same as yours

Comment: is there a way to have the ul act like a div and force 100% width?

Comment: you can keep the 100% width of the parent ul by assigning it a width: 100%, but keep in mind that if you modify its margins or paddings you will need to take them in account too

Comment: float elements automatically adapt their size to fit that of their contents, so they no longer act as common block elements. To restore this behaviour you need to specify manually the desided width. Unfortunately, if your element has lateral margins or paddings set, setting a width of 100% wont'work, but you will have to subtract them from the total width

Answer (score 0):

If you add the style

```
display:block;
```

The li's will render as block level elements, and you should then be able to style them up just like the Div based example. You might need to float them left to get them next to each other exactly like your example page. (or use inline-block instead of block perhaps)

Try this (I haven't tested this as I'm on my little laptop - this is based on memory / guesswork)

```
<style>
    #horizontallist li { display: block; float:left; }
    .alone { background: #E5ECF9; border: 1px solid #336699; color: #336699;  }
    .group { background: #FBE3E4; border: 1px solid #CC0000; color: #CC0000; }
    .group .not_alone { background: #FBE3E4; border: 1px solid #CC0000; color: #CC0000; }
    .item { padding: 2px; margin: 0 2px; }
</style>

<ul id="horizontallist">
    <li class="alone item">List Item 1</li>
    <li class="alone item">List Item 2</li>
    <li class="alone item">List Item 3</li>
    <li class="group item">List Item 4
      <ul>
        <li class="group item">List Item 4a</li>
        <li class="group item">List Item 4b</li>
        <li class="group item">List Item 4c</li>
        <li class="group item">List Item 4d</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="alone">List Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: inline-block mode is not fully supported in IE fon non-native inline elements: see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: @Lucius - Thanks, I've edited my example to use block and float instead. I also stuck a class on the ul, to make these fairly dramatic styles more specific. (It would have been an ID, but I'm on my mac, and embarrasingly don't know how to type a hash/pound sign).

Comment: @Lucius - And now I've learnt how to get the # symbol on my UK mac, I've edited it again (alt+3 if anyone's wondering).

Comment: it seems that everything looks fine apart from the "List Item 4" text which sits ontop of the rest of the other "List Item 4*". You can see what I'm talking about here http://fiddle.jshell.net/gWbs9/ - any ideas on how to make this align with the rest of the li elements?

Also is there way to make the parent ul behave like a div and have 100% width?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (requires jQuery):

```
var wrapper = $("body").append("<div id='wrapper'></div>").find("#wrapper");

var lis = $("ul > li");

lis.each(function() {
    var li = $(this);
    if (li.hasClass("alone")) wrapper.append("<div class = 'alone item' >" + li.text() + " </div>");
    else if (li.hasClass("group")) {
        var html = "<div class='group item'>";
        li.find("li").each(function() {
            html += "<div class = 'group item' >" + $(this).text() + " </div>";
        });
        html += "</div>";
        wrapper.append(html);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/EJZMS/show/light/

Code: http://fiddle.jshell.net/EJZMS/

My code is not recursive: If you have more than one level of nesting, you will need to modify it yourself.

Comment: you should prefer static css rules to JS, since you cannot be sure whether all your user have it enabled..

Comment: That's up to OP. I'm just trying to give them as many options as possible

Comment: unfortunately I'm looking for only a CSS based solution, pretty cool method though! Thanks.